# How to get a list/vector of which clusters a node in a network has belonged to when the clusters change at each timestep?

Tags: matlab, k-means

I have used kmeans to cluster a population in Matlab and then I run a disease in the population and nodes that have the disease more than 80% of the time are excluded from the clustering - meaning the clusters change each iteration. Then it reclusters over 99 timesteps. How do I create a vector/list of which clusters a specific node has belonged to over the whole time period?

I have tried using the vector created by kmeans called 'id' but this doesn't include the nodes that are excluded from the clustering so I cannot track one specific node as the size of id changes each time. This is what I tried and ran it in the for loop so it plotted a line plot for each iteration:

```
nt = [nt sum(id(1,:))];
```

Only problem was that the first row in the vector obviously changed every timestep so it wasn't the same person.

This is my initial simple clustering:

```
%Cluster the population according to these features

[id, c] = kmeans(feats', 5);
```

Then this is the reclustering process to exclude those who have the disease for more than 80% of the time (this part is in a big for loop in the whole code):

```
Lc = find(m < 0.8);

    if t > 1,

        [id, c, sumD, D] = kmeans(feats(:, Lc)', 5, 'Start', c);

    else,

    [id, c, sumD, D] = kmeans(feats(:, Lc)', 5);

    end;
```

I want to be able to plot and track the fate of specific nodes in my population which is why I want to know how their cluster groups change. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What I dont understand is, when you exclude a node from clustering, why are you surprised that you cannot track them? Your problem seems to be, that you loose the overview of your indices when excluding elements, it has nothing to do with kmean itself? For a better understanding include a short example with the desired input / ouput behavior and what you are getting right now...

Comment: Thank you very much, I see your point about focusing too much on the kmeans.